# Writing Linux Bash script

Tags: shell-script

I have bash script

```
#!/bin/sh

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive;

apt-get update;
apt-get -y upgrade;

apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev nginx;

##After the command output shows visible commands after + sign in bash
set -x -e 

pip install virtualenv;
virtualenv /home/user/virtualenv;
source /home/user/virtualenv/bin/activate;

pip install gunicorn;

systemctl start gunicorn;
systemctl restart nginx;
```

The Output of command show like

```
+ virtualenv /home/user/virtualenv
New python executable in /home/user/virtualenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
+ source /home/user/virtualenv/bin/activate
++ deactivate nondestructive
++ unset -f pydoc
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -n /bin/bash ']'
++ hash -r
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ unset VIRTUAL_ENV
++ '[' '!' nondestructive = nondestructive ']'
++ VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/user/virtualenv
++ export VIRTUAL_ENV
++ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
++ PATH=/var/www/html/askbotenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
++ export PATH
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1=
++ '[' x '!=' x ']'
+++ basename /home/user/virtualenv
++ PS1='(askbotenv) '
++ export PS1
++ alias pydoc
++ '[' -n /bin/bash ']'
++ hash -r
+ pip install gunicorn
Collecting gunicorn
```

I want to remove those `+` sign before the command due to `set -x -e`

Comment: Use parentheses to start subshells.

Comment: (What makes you think `set -x -e` enters a sub-process?)

Comment: So remove -x ...?

Comment: @jeff-schaller Thanks a lot it helps me lot Regards :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `set -x -e` command will turn on tracing with the `-x` (this is what produces the `+` prompts in the output) and will also make the script exit directly if anything goes wrong with the `-e`.

Having the script exit directly at an error my still be a good thing though, so I'd suggest changing the line to only say

```
set -e
```

Alternatively, since the trace is outputted to the standard error stream, you may instead redirect that to `/dev/null` when running the script:

```
$ ./myscript 2>/dev/null
```

... but this would also discard any other diagnostic message that you might actually want to see.

Comment: It works for me 101% thanks a lot.. :)